# xulrunner 17.0.1 browser content links require doubleclick (instead of a single click) on Mac OSX 10.7.x

Tags: html, osx-lion, xulrunner

I am using xulrunner 17.0.1 to convert a web base HTML 5 application to a standalone desktop application. The target platforms are Window XP + and Mac 10.6 +.

While I am able to package and run my HTML 5 application with XULRunner on window without any trouble, I am facing a weird issue on the Mac. Everything seems to be working fine except for I have to double click (instead of single click) on a link of my HTML 5 application to make it works.

To ensure that problem is not in the HTML 5 application I opened mozilla/other websites in the browser component and found that problem is with any content.

Is there any preference setting that I need to change?

Thanks
-pk

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of the problem. I was running my application from Terminal and somehow the focus was always going back to the terminal window, therefore the link were working on double click only. On first click my application window was getting the focus and on second click the link was registering the click event. Similarly the text box were also not taking inputs from keyboard.

I packaged my application as an app using the guidelines provided at "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner/Deploying_XULRunner_1.8" and that solved all the problems. Everything started working as per expectation.